# Is there a way to apply shapes and text in Windows Snipping Tool?

Tags: windows-10

Windows Snipping tool drawing and delay features are great, but I often find myself trying to write on snips, and drawing arrows.

So from time to time i'm forced to copy paste to Microsoft power point, turning this into a two program step.

Is there a way to enable shapes, and text in snipping tool, or some sort of plug in?

Comment: No, this will always be a 2-way step. Other programs do offer this, but then too it is a 2 way step. For example with Greenshot, you first capture your rectangle, then you can automatically make it open in the Greenshot editor, then you add your arrows and text, but then you still have to either save or copy it back to the clipboard.

Comment: Wait, I misread 2-program step as 2-way step. Yes that is possible. See above note ^. xD

Comment: @LPChip, thanks! this alternative is an acceptable answer for me

Comment: Just a heads-up. Since the latest windows 10 version: 1809, the replacement for the snippingtool by microsoft will have support to directly draw on your capture.

Comment: What about the snip n sketch tool?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The snipping tool itself can't really do this, so that makes this a software recommendation which really is considered Off-Topic here.

I gave [Greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org/) as an example in my comments because that is what I use which is a full featured screenshot program.

Normally this question would be closed for being off-topic, but given that I misread your question, I guess you are lucky. :)

Greenshot does come with an editor where you can easily add arrows, text, shapes, blur out/pixelate sensitive information and besides it being free and open-source, it also is featured with auto-installers such as Ninite and PatchMyPC.

In my setup, I've set Greenshot to automatically copy the screenshot to the clipboard, and the greenshot icon is always shown in the taskbar. If I need to edit it, I can then right-click the greenshot icon and choose: Open Image from clipboard to access it in the editor. Once done, I then either save the image there or choose copy to clipboard, to send the edited version back to the clipboard, ready to be pasted somewhere else.